# Formal terminology: metafeatures then groupby (GROUP BY) operation

Tags: pandas, sql, terminology, features, groupby

In ML training and other analytics I often combine features to produce a 'metafeature' and then perform a 'groupby' (pandas) or 'GROUP BY' (SQL) query. What is the technical term for this operation?

Example, in my work I will combine taxonomy, e.g. the *genus* with a given gene function and gene variant. You could instead consider geographic location of an individual with age and/or occupation, e,g,

| location | name | age | first name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| California | Aderson | 34 | Jill |
| NewYork | Smith | 25 | Mark |
| California | Aderson | 34 | Bob |

Group by operation...

| Metafeature | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| California-Aderson-34 | 2 |
| NewYork-Smith-25 | 1 |

Comment: I just consider this grouping by multiple features.

Comment: Thanks @BenReiniger